# Migrating Stored Procedures to CakePHP 3.0

Tags: cakephp

What is the best practice for migrating a CakePHP 2 project that uses Views in MySQL to a CakePHP 3 projects that uses migrations. As I understand it, there is no support for Stored Procedures/Views in the Phinx library but I would like to continue accessing the View as if it were a table e.g appending conditions.

If there is no best practice then please outline the options that I would have available to me.